# Modifying the elements of an Arraylist with 1D-Array inside

Tags: excel, vba, arraylist

Using Excel VBA, if we create an **ArrayList** where one of its items is a **one-dimensional array**, how can we modify its elements? Below we have a code that do not work properly.

```
Sub foobar()
      Dim MyArrayList As New ArrayList
      MyArrayList.Add "hello"
      MyArrayList.Add Array("a", "b")
      Debug.Print MyArrayList.Item(0) 'returns the word 'hello'
      Debug.Print MyArrayList.Item(1)(0) 'returns the letter 'a'
      MyArrayList.Item(0) = "bye"
      MyArrayList.Item(1)(0) = "z"
      Debug.Print MyArrayList.Item(0) 'returns the word 'bye'
      Debug.Print MyArrayList.Item(1)(0) 'keep returning the letter 'a'
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to replace the whole item and not just part. `MyArrayList.Item(0) = array("z","y")`

Comment: Thank you Scott. Unfortunatelly arraylist is not as awesome as I thought.

Comment: use a dictionary object

Comment: Thank you for the tip Sorceri, but since I need to use Sorting a lot, use Dictionary object may handle this issue, but will create another.

Comment: @ScottCraner is definitely correct.  You can do something like `V=myArrayList.Item(1) : V(0) = "z" : myArrayList.Item(1)=V`

Comment: Elegant solution Ron, thank you!